# Using a template class in multiple classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

Suppose I have 3 classes as shown[image]

Instead of the functions in the object class I would like to create a single template function which can take the place of the two functions in the object class.  The issue I am having is I do not know how to allow the template function to take arguments either of type modifier_1 or type modifier_2.  Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: please do not include code as images. Include code as text. And better try something and show your attempt. It is not clear why you have problems to write a method template that accepts either of the two. I could understand if your problem was that the method accepts not only the two but also anything else, but currently it is unclear what is the problem

Comment: btw both your methods dont use `mod_1` / `mod_2`, they are merely adding two `int`s, you could remove that unused parameter and your "problem" is gone

Comment: @idclev463035818 ...unless this is a simplified & distilled example, while in the real code the parameters are actually used.

Comment: @lisyarus in that case it is distilled to an extend that the essence is gone and as such useless as a mcve. In the posted code there is no way to know why removing the unused parameter is not the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 3 solutions that might work for what you want.

1.

```
class object : public modifier_1, public modifier_2
{
private:
   int x{};
   template<class Modifier>
   void modify_by_modifier_helper(Modifier mod, int modifier)
   {
      x += modifier;
   }
public:
   object() = default;
   void modify_by_modifier(modifier_1 mod, int modifier)
   {
      modify_by_modifier_helper(mod, modifier);
   }

   void modify_by_modifier(modifier_2 mod, int modifier)
   {
      modify_by_modifier_helper(mod, modifier);
   }
};
```

2.

```
#include <type_traits>

class object : public modifier_1, public modifier_2
{
private:
   int x{};
public:
   object() = default;

   template<class Modifier>
   void modify_by_modifier(Modifier mod, int modifier)
   {
      static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Modifier>, modifier_1> ||
         std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Modifier>, modifier_2>,
         "Modifier must be modifier_1 or modifier_2")

      x += modifier;
   }
};
```

3.

```
#include <type_traits>

class object : public modifier_1, public modifier_2
{
private:
   int x{};
public:
   object() = default;

   template<class Modifier>
   std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Modifier>, modifier_1> ||
         std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Modifier>, modifier_2>, void>
   modify_by_modifier(Modifier mod, int modifier)
   {
      x += modifier;
   }
};
```

Comment: Does the first solution make the object class abstract?  I am now unable to instantiate it.

Comment: @CosmicCoder123 No it shouldn't make it abstract. I tested it with g++ and clang++ and I seam to be able to instantiate it.

Comment: @Issac Clancy I think that method is what I want, but for some reason it has made my object class abstract compiling in Visual Studio 2019. So I cannot instantiate an object.

Comment: @CosmicCoder123 I tested it in Visual Studio 2019 and it worked. Try changing  `object() = default;` to `object() {}` and see what error Visual Studio gives you.

Comment: that gives
Warning C4930 'object object(void)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)

Comment: your code works when I copy it exactly, it's just for some reason in my more complicated code where I am looking to apply this I cannot instantiate the object class

Comment: @CosmicCoder123 if you are instantiating your object like this `object o();` try instantiating your object like this `object o{};`

Comment: The seemingly random errors I was getting were caused by typing something like template<class Modifier>
   void modify_by_modifier_helper(Modifier Modifier, int Modifier) and I think the programme got confused. Now I understand why it is important to name your distinguish between your variable types and the argument they refer to in the function.